# Module loaded even though it's blacklisted

Tags: blacklist, modprobe

System: Ubuntu 11.10

```
Linux gray 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to blacklist a module (rt2800usb among other) like;

```
$ lsmod | grep rt
rt2800usb              22300  0 
rt2800lib              48717  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              20092  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48114  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
mac80211              272785  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              172392  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
$ emacs /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add:

```
blacklist rt2800usb
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00lib
```

and then:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$ sudo reboot
```

But the module are loaded after reboot:

```
$ lsmod | grep rt
rt2800usb              22300  0 
rt2800lib              48717  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              20092  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48114  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
mac80211              272785  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              172392  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
```

How do I make the changes persist (i.e. have the modules blacklisted) after reboot?

Comment: What hardware are you trying to get working ? I suspect your modules are getting loaded as they are used by other modules (cfg80211) , so you will need to specify the proper, alternate modules to use.

Comment: I figured it might be another module that force the loading. I'm trying to maximize my usb-network device, I get low ping (200ms on local network) and slow speed (200kb/s on local network). To lower the ping I have figured that `iwconfig wlan0 power off` works well, I still have slow speed though.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from *lsmod* output:

```
rt2800usb              22300  0 
rt2800lib              48717  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              20092  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48114  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
mac80211              272785  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              172392  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
```

*rt2800usb* and *rt2800lib* **are used by module** *rt2x00lib* which itself is used by **cfg80211**

Thus these two modules you blacklisted are neccaissary to load module *cfg80211* which is NOT blacklisted. That is why they are loaded despite are blacklisted.